# Avro iterate over GenericRecord

Tags: java, avro

I have a GenericRecord, and want to iterate over the entire collection of key/values. The record is a java data structure that is the equivalent of a plain json string. Eg:

```
    {"key1":"val1","key2":val2",...} but is quite long.
```

The problem is, I dont know how many key,vals are inside it.

I've tried:

```
    AvroKeyValue<String,String> kv = new AvroKeyValue<>(record);
    Iterator<String,String> iterator = new AvroKeyValue.Iterator<String,String>(kv);
```

But this does not work.

The apache docs about it are here:
http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.0/api/java/org/apache/avro/hadoop/io/AvroKeyValue.Iterator.html

Comment: Does not work is neither precise nor helpful. What's exactly not working?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `GenericRecord`'s schema to list the available fields

```
for (Field field : record.getSchema().getFields()) {
    String fieldKey = field.name();
    System.out.println(fieldKey + " : " + record.get(fieldKey));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of fields of a `GenericRecord` with:

```
record.getSchema().getFields().size();
```