# Different Avro Namespaces for Producer and Consumer

Tags: java, avro

Referring to the answer in: [Different Namespaces for Producer and Consumer Avro Schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082436/different-namespaces-for-producer-and-consumer-avro-schemas/64577862#64577862)

I tried below two approaches but neither works.  If namespace is not different then both works.

**APPROACH 1 - SchemaRegistry and confluent serde**
(added base on feedback from Jun 20/21)

```java
        var config = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,"http://localhost:8081");
        var der = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
        der.configure(config,false);
        var ser = new KafkaAvroSerializer();
        ser.configure(config,false);

        var producerRecord = (new GenericRecordBuilder(writerSchema)).build();
        producerRecord.put("Foo","123");

        final var bytes = ser.serialize("topic",producerRecord);
        var readerRecord = (GenericRecord)der.deserialize("topic",bytes,readerSchema);

        readerRecord.get("Bar") => null, expects to be "123"
```

Reader/Writer schemas used:

```
{
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "namespace": "ReaderNamespace",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Bar",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null,
      "aliases": [
        "Foo",
        "WriterNamespace.Foo"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "namespace": "WriterNamespace",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Foo",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**APPROACH 2 - GenericDatumReader/Writer**

```java
      // create producer record with writer schema
      //
      GenericRecord producerRecord = (new GenericRecordBuilder(writerSchema)).build();
      producerRecord.put("Foo",123);

      // convert into byte[] using GenericDatumWriter
      //
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      Encoder writerEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(out, null);
      DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(producerRecord.getSchema());
      writer.write(producerRecord, writerEncoder);
      byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();

      // try convert from byte[] using GenericDatumReader by providing both writer and reader schema 
      //
      BinaryDecoder readerDecoder = new DecoderFactory().binaryDecoder(byteArray, null);
      DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(producerRecord.getSchema(), readerSchema);
      GenericRecord readerRecord = reader.read(null, readerDecoder);
```

But is still throwing exception on reading the producer record.  What would be missing?

```
    org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found WriterNamespace.MyRecord, expecting ReaderNamespace.MyRecord, missing required field Bar
        at app//org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:308)
        at app//org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:86)
        at app//org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readFieldOrder(ResolvingDecoder.java:127)
        at app//org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:240)
        at app//org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
        at app//org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
        at app//org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
```

Writer schema:

```json
{
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "namespace": "WriterNamespace",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Foo",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Reader schema:

```json
{
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "namespace": "ReaderNamespace",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Bar",
      "type": "int",
      "aliases": ["Foo"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use a Schema Registry? It was built to handle this use case

Comment: Producer did use schema registry. I.e. producerRecord.getSchema() is the schema maintained in the registry.  It is the consumer who need to consume multiple writer schema so prefer to use one schema.   According to Avro spec, this should be supported: both schemas are records with the same (unqualified) name

Comment: Avro spec: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution

We refer to the schema used to write the data as the writer's schema, and the schema that the application expects the reader's schema. Differences between these should be resolved as follows:

It is an error if the two schemas do not match.
To match, one of the following must hold:
...
both schemas are records with the same (unqualified) name

Comment: In your consumer, then, what is `byteArray`? Does that contain the magic byte from the registry serializer, or have you removed that? Also, if the consumer can reach the Registry over HTTP, then why not let it get the schema, and then map that data into a different record rather than trying to deserialize to a completely different record type? You cannot rename a field, and the alias should be fully qualified with the namespace

Comment: Above example is after schema registry.  byteArray is created by GenericDatumWriter.  GenericDatumReader is supposed to take the writer schema to deserialise the byte array and resolve it to the reader schema.  This all works fine when namespace is same.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point/question, but what happens when you use `"aliases": ["WriterNamespace.MyRecord.Foo"]`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your requirement is to get rid of the schema dependency while reading the Kafka events, then I would suggest to make use of "GenericRecord" in consumer.

Please find :
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#avro-deserializer

You may need to traverse the elements like an xml/json parser : [Avro iterate over GenericRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628143/avro-iterate-over-genericrecord)

But why do you need to alter the namespace in consumer? Do you have any conflict in existing schema? If thats the case then you may merge the existing schema with the new one as optional element, so that it can work for both and more clean code.

Comment: I am trying to use Avro to absorb the differences between reader and writer schema - as reader and writer can evolve separately and there can be many readers (with slightly different versions) and many writers (again with slightly different versions).

Comment: My recommendation would be to evolve the schema eventually rather than totally getting rid of it.

Comment: The intention is not to get rid of any schema.  But to allow reader and writer use their own schema to communicate.  And without forcing reader and writer to pick only one schema.

Comment: @rmcv If you are using a Schema Registry, then consumers can already use different versions of the schema than the producer, and you don't need to write your own Kafka deserializer https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html